# Large array programming in PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded

I would like to play musical notes using a PIC microcontroller 16F887.  I want to store the frequency of 109 musical notes in an array of type `float`, then call the needed frequency to play.

The problem is that when I have created the array as follows using mikroC, the compiler says: not enough RAM:

```c
float notes_freq[109] = 
{
16.35,17.32,18.35,19.45,20.60,21.83,23.12,24.50,25.96,27.50,29.14,30.87,32.70,34.65,36.71,38.89,                  
41.20,43.65,46.25,49.00,51.91,55.00,58.27,61.74,65.41,69.30,73.42,77.78,82.41,87.31,92.50,98.00,                  
103.83,110.00,116.54,123.47,130.81,138.59,146.83,155.56,164.81,174.61,185.00,196.00,207.65,220.00,                  
233.08,246.94,261.63,277.18,293.66,311.13,329.63,349.23,369.99,392.00,415.30,440.00,466.16,493.88,                   
523.25,554.37,587.33,622.25,659.25,698.46,739.99,783.99,830.61,880.00,932.33,987.77,1046.50,1108.73,                 
1174.66,1244.51,1318.51,1396.91,1479.98,1567.98,1661.22,1760.00,1864.66,1975.53,2093.00,2217.46,2349.32,            
2489.02,2637.02,2793.83,2959.96,3135.96,3322.44,3520.00,3729.31,3951.07,4186.01,4434.92,4698.63,4978.03,5274.04,5587.65,5919.91,6271.93,6644.8
8,7040.00,7458.62,7902.13
};
```

I understand that the PIC RAM is full. How can I overcome this issue? Can I store the array in EEPROM? If so, how can I do it at compile time?

Comment: What does your consultation of your compiler's documentation reveal, how to store constant data in flash memory? You might need the keyword `const` and perhaps some compiler specific "hint" in the source code.

Comment: Note that the PIC16F887, as well as many other chips in this class, lacks a floating-point unit (FPU). Consequently any floating point operations must be emulated by the compiler (if the compiler supports this), which is extremely slow. Use integer / "fixed-point" techniques instead wherever possible.

Comment: I'm curious how these floats are going to be converted into frequencies anyway on a PIC. I'd have thought that having a timer controlled by a uint32_t or similar would be the way to go, in which case floats are not going to be helpful.

Comment: If memory and performance requirements allow, the software can calculate timer parameters from the floating point values. This array is perfectly abstract. As source code should make the programmer's intent clear for future readers, defining integer values for the timer would only be necessary if requirements are not met otherwise. Else I would call it premature optimization, which is worse maintainable. ;-)

Comment: You might be better converting your code to use fixed point, which is much more efficient on small MCUs.

Comment: @thebusybee No, avoiding "float" types is not a premature optimization when programming for an integer-only platform. This class of low-performance platform has tight requirements that can't usually be ignored the way they are in large scale (desktop, server, even mobile SoC) software development.

Comment: Forget floats on a small MCU, use Ints

Comment: @thebusybee - although I do agree with you in the general case, when you're writing code for a little slow MCU like the OP's 16F887 you need to be much more aware and accommodating of these issues right from the start. Choosing to use fix-point math here is not premature optimization - it's a sensible design choice.

Comment: As I said, **if** the requirements permit, be as expressive and abstract as possible. All the reasons you name are good and well, and they apply **if** requirements could not be met otherwise. -- The time saved because future readers don't have to read potentially complex comments, to check that the transformations are right, and to grasp the code, outweighs any unnecessary optimization. -- Anyway, you need to have requirements! This is the core of any reasonable development, never work without. -- However, this point is not the issue of the question, and is subject of opinions.

Comment: Oh, and I did embedded development for 8-bitters for more than 30 years now, 8051, PIC, and so on. :-D I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you planning on the code choosing the note to play by specifying the index into the array? I think this might be a time when a header file with a set of #defines might be better. _play_note(NOTE_D0); play_note(NOTE_A4)_ seems more coder-friendly than _play_note(17); play_note(36);_

Comment: @spuck, I agree with you, it would be better with #define statement, but it is just a start point to discover sounds playing in PICs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Make the array constant with the modifier `const`, as you only need to read the values.
2. Add the compiler specific keyword `code` to locate the array in (flash) ROM.

```c
const float code notes_freq[] = { 16.35, /* ... */ };
```

*Note: You don't need to specify the size of the array, which is error prone as you will count the values manually. Let the compiler count them.*

Comment: I don't think you need 'code' for XC8 (or Hitech C). Just const.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The OP uses microC, as the question states. And I used "compiler specific" in my answer. ;-)

Comment: Okay, I'll leave the comment for future reference.

Comment: "You don't need to specify the size of the array, which is error prone" You don't need to but doing so provides a useful cross-check that you provided the expected number of entries. Otherwise the compiler will silently build an array with an incorrect number of entries. Good luck finding that in debug.

Comment: @GrahamNye This only works if the specified size is smaller than the number of provided elements. The other way around unspecified elements are silently zero-initialized. I see no gain. If you need an size check, do it explicitely by one of the usual methods. As a sidenote, even hobbyist's project should do testing. ;-)

Comment: Agree with not explicitly setting the array size. Does microC support static asserts? You could use that as a compile-time check on the size of the array if it does.

Comment: @brhans One common "trick" is a typedef for an array with a positive size in the good case, and a negative size in the bad case: `typedef char expressive_name_for_check[2 * condition - 1];` No need for advanced features in the compiler, only to invent some expressive type name. :-D Typedefs do not take memory in the final application and are local to the translation unit.

Comment: @thebusybee Oh, well, half right. I see the case of zero filling of unspecified initializers of a fixed size array is covered in A8.6 (1st ed) and A8.7 (2nd ed) of _K&R_.

Comment: @GrahamNye ROTFL, it is always funny to see references to books or standards of the stone age of CS. K&R 2nd ed. is about 35 years old... Granted, I learned C with the 1st edition, but now it is 2022. Anyway, the current standard says the same: silent filling with zeroes.

Comment: @thebusybee: I regard K&R2 as a more accurate description of the language the Standard was *chartered to describe* than the Standard itself is.  In K&R2, if `unsigned int x;` is 32 bits and `unsigned short y,z;` are 16, the effects of `x=y*z;` K&R would describe the effect of `x=y*z;` as "machine dependent" when the mathematical product exceeds 0x7FFFFFFF; the Standard allows implementations to behave in arbitrarily nonsensical fashion in such cases, an allowance gcc treats as an invitation.

Comment: @thebusybee: If I had been in charge of the C Standard, I would have provided a means of indicating whether an array whose contents aren't fully specified should be zero-filled, left uninitialized, or regarded as an error.  All three treatments are useful in some circumstances, and it's unfortunate that the language only supports one.

Comment: @supercat Well, we need to cope with C's history and its not quite perfect standard. That got better over the years but still has room for improvement. Tools help to fill the gaps, but the perfect programming language still needs to be invented. ;-) Anyway, we cannot change anything, just learn the details.

Comment: @thebusybee: C99 basically killed useful innovation.  Prior to C99, people recognized that the Standard was supposed to be a formal description of the pre-existing language which was also specified by K&R2, and that constructs which were defined in K&R2 but not the Standard represented omissions in the Standard.  Following C99, however, omission of constructs from the Standard has been interpreted by some compiler maintainers as implying that any code relying upon such constructs should be viewed as "broken".

Comment: @GrahamNye Using an unspecified array size and then static assert to verify the size, is the safest and most correct way to implement this. On modern standard C you'd do `_Static_assert(sizeof notes_freq / sizeof *notes_freq == EXPECTED_SIZE, "notes_freq got the wrong number of items");` On very old compilers (>13 years old) you'd use some trick like the typedef array example busybee showed. The problem with specifying a fixed size is indeed that the compiler can spot if there are too many items, but not if there are too few.

Comment: @Lundin "_(>13 years old)_" ... or younger, but of lesser quality. I have no personal experience with microC, but enough with other compilers for embedded control. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee PIC compilers are unfortunately notorious for being non-conforming crap. Other than that, all the well-known embedded compiler vendors support C11 since forever. And those older than that might still have `static_assert` available from being able to compile C++03.

Answer (score 12):

Even if you say so, you actually don't want or need to store 109 floats.

First of all, each octave is 12 notes only and next and previous octaves are gotten by doubling or halving the frequencies.

And they don't need to be floats either, just pick 12 highest notes you want to support and use the frequencies as integers. If you want higher than 1 Hz precision then use the octave that scales between 32768 and 65535 Hz and shift it down to any octave you want as there will likely be more precision you can ever use to generate a tone. Depends on how you generate the tone though, with frequency divider or DDS.

If you want to avoid math with frequencies then it might be better to not store the frequencies at all but the precalculated values you actually need to produce those frequencies.

If you don't use floats you have more room storing intermediate notes for sliding and finetuning between the 12 notes of an octave.

Comment: "First of all, each octave is 12 notes only and next and previous octaves are gotten by doubling or halving the frequencies.", Can explaine it more, or give me a reference or example code to do that, because I did not grasp the point.

Comment: @learndesign You need to learn basics of music theory to understand that but you don't need to learn it if you just want to code it. Just look at your frequency table. Take middle A note with 440 Hz, go up or down an octave, and you land up at note A with 880 Hz or 220 Hz which is double or half the 440 Hz. Therefore you only need a table of all notes within an octave, 12.

Comment: Using a frequency table that includes a 16-bit value for each distinct note is hardly unreasonable--it's what I usually do, though if one wanted to be maximally compact one should store note numbers as a 4-bit octave part and a 4-bit note-within-octave part, and have a table of 8-bit values from 30-60, 60-120, or 120 to 240 and scale things up from there, preferably playing music in the key represented by pitch values that are power-of-two multiples of 30.

Comment: @supercat separating note and octave to their own nybbles is neat as it avoids math or tables. Compare that to MIDI where a note number 0-127 must be divded by 12 to get octave and modulo 12 to get the note, before you can look up a frequency or other value and scale it to correct octave.

Comment: @Justme: On the flip side, separating note and octave complicates some operations such as transposing music up or down by some number of half steps, and also increases the size of frequency table needed to hold every frequency individually (on a properly-tuned acoustic piano or faithful imitation thereof, notes an octave apart will have a frequency ratio that is just a smidgen over 2:1).

Comment: @Justme: Almost all of the music players I have done used straight note numbers, except for the BTP2 music player which had for each output volume a set of twelve waveforms along with code that could play each wave at quarter, half, normal, double, or quadruple speed.  Since the playback method would be selected based upon the octave, separating things by octave number made sense.  It also made things nice when trying note numbers in hex.

Comment: @supercat Good point, which is why the MIDI way makes sense. And typically for any normal purpose the 12 notes with octaves is enough, the intricasies of emulating a properly tuned acoustic piano is typically a special case not needed for generic sound chip handling (OPL, SAA1099), but can of course be handled through adjustable fine tuning for each note (also available via MIDI).

Answer (score 2):

This is just answering a comment from the OP.

Justme rightfully wrote:

> each octave is 12 notes only and next and previous octaves are gotten
> by doubling or halving the frequencies.

learn design replied:

> Can explaine it more, or give me a reference or example code to do
> that, because I did not grasp the point.

If you format your array with 12 frequencies per source line, it should
look like this:

```c
float notes_freq[109] = {
    16.35, 17.32, 18.35, 19.45, 20.60, 21.83, 23.12, 24.50, ...
    32.70, 34.65, 36.71, 38.89, 41.20, 43.65, 46.25, 49.00, ...
    65.41, 69.30, 73.42, 77.78, 82.41, 87.31, 92.50, 98.00, ...
    ...
};
```

Each row of 12 notes is called an “octave”. Note that from one octave to
the next, the frequencies are multiplied by two. Then, you do not need
to store the whole array: you can store just the first octave, and then
compute any other frequency by multiplying the appropriate note (from
the first octave) by a suitable power of two.

Example code:

```c
float notes_freq[12] = { 16.351598, 17.323914, ... };

float note_frequency(int note)
{
    int multiplier = 1;
    while (note >= 12) {
        note -= 12;
        multiplier <<= 1;
    }
    return notes_freq[note] * multiplier;
}
```

You may want to add some bound checks.

Comment: A few notes, the table is still floats and it is in ram and they both are unncessary on a small micro. The loop is nice on a small micro to reduce complex math, but division and modulo might demonstrate the idea better.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/629971/217935) actually offers the best solution to your specific problem.

However, for the more general case, you can often save a lot of space and a lot of CPU cycles in microcontroller programming by completely bypassing the need for `float` variables and instead storing your values in [Q/Fixed Point format](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/fixed-point-representation-the-q-format-and-addition-examples/).

The long and short of it is that you take your fractional number and store it in an integer, left shifted by some amount (the amount is a trade off between space needed and precision). You then do your calculations with these integer values (you need to adjust the shift for certain operations) which is far faster than with floats. Then when you want your result, you right shift your integer right back out.

For reasonably low precisions, like yours, this saves on *both* the RAM requirements and CPU cycles. If you needed higher precision, the RAM requirements have less of a saving but the CPU saving of doing integer operations is almost always worth it on an MCU without an FPU even if you end up using huge integers.

Comment: This, like other answers, misses a general important point: Why should the OP store constant values in _RAM_, if these values are only read and never written? The program needs to have the values in _ROM_ anyway, to initialize the variables in RAM, and some code to do so. I would not waste precious RAM space for constant values. -- However, the point of reducing the size of such constants, is independent from the first point. In so far such answers are valuable, but answer another question.

Comment: @thebusybee - I don't think I have missed the point here, the answer I said was ideal for this use case avoids storing these values at all, which I think is even better than storing them in ROM given how valuable ROM space can be and how easily these values can be calculated. Whilst, sure, my answer is somewhat tangential, I think it still adds value because it can be used in conjunction with any of the answers above to make them more effective

Comment: The method where I said in my answer to use as large as integers as possible, is basically same as using fixed point without using the word fixed point. That's because you always divide down, or shift, the value to smaller, as frequencies in the table are absurdly high for human ears. It's up to the user to either use or discard the fractional bits.

Comment: @Justme - To be honest, I missed that... I saw the essence of your answer about being calculating them on the fly and not bothering with the fractional parts of the frequency rather than this being sort of pseudo-fixed-point